# Using brace expansion to move files on the command line

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I have a question concerning why this doesn't work. Probably, it's a simple answer, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I want to move a couple of files I have. They all have the same filename (let's say file1) but they are all in different directories (lets say /tmp/dir1,dir2 and dir3). If I were to move these individually I could do something along the lines of:

`mv /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp`

That works. However, I have multiple directories and they're all going to end up in the same spot....AND I don't want to overwrite. So, I tried something like this:

`mv /tmp/{dir1,dir2,dir3}/file1 /tmp/file1.{a,b,c}`

When I try this I get:

/tmp/file1.c is not a directory

Just to clarify...this also works:

`mv /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/file1.c`

Pretty sure this has to do with brace expansion but not certain why.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use a loop; brace expansion is purely a shortcut  and doesn't let you do anything you couldn't do by typing arguments out by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Just do `echo` to understand how the shell expands:

```
$ echo mv /tmp/{dir1,dir2,dir3}/file1 /tmp/file1.{a,b,c}
mv /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/dir2/file1 /tmp/dir3/file1 /tmp/file1.a /tmp/file1.b /tmp/file1.c
```

Now you can see that your command is not what you want, because in a `mv` command, the destination (directory or file) is the last argument.

Comment: And any time there are more than two arguments, the last one is expected to be a directory into which all the others should go.

Answer (score 0):

That's unfortunately now how the shell expansion works.

You'll have to probably use an associative array.

```sh
!/bin/bash

declare -A MAP=( [dir1]=a [dir2]=b [dir3]=c )

for ext in "${!MAP[@]}"; do
    echo mv "/tmp/$ext/file1" "/tmp/file1.${MAP[$ext]}"
done
```

You get the following output when you run it:

```
mv /tmp/dir2/file1 /tmp/file1.b
mv /tmp/dir3/file1 /tmp/file1.c
mv /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/file1.a
```

Like with many other languages key ordering is not guaranteed.

`${!MAP[@]}` returns an array of all the keys, while `${MAP[@]}` returns the an array of all the values.

---

Your syntax of `/tmp/{dir1,dir2,dir3}/file1` expands to `/tmp/dir1/file /tmp/dir2/file /tmp/dir3/file`. This is similar to the way the `*` expansion works. The shell does not execute your command with each possible combination, it simply executes the command but expands your one value to as many as are required.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of a/b/c you could differentiate them with the actual number of the dir they came from?

```
$: for d in 1 2 3
   do echo mv /tmp/dir$d/file1 /tmp/file1.$d
   done
mv /tmp/dir1/file1 /tmp/file1.1
mv /tmp/dir2/file1 /tmp/file1.2
mv /tmp/dir3/file1 /tmp/file1.3
```

When happy with it, take out the `echo`.

A relevant point - brace expansion *is not a wildcard*. It has nothing to do with what's on disk. It just creates strings.

So, if you create a bunch of files named with single letters or digits, `echo ?` will wildcard and list them all, but only the ones actually present. If there are files for vowels but not consonants, only the vowels will show. But -

if you say `echo {foo,bar,nope}` it will output `foo bar nope` regardless of whether or not any or all of those exist as files or directories, etc.